# C# SqLite Custom build sqlite3.dll location

Tags: c#, sqlite

My problem is;

I need to make a sqlite table that has approximately 6400 columns. (I know it's not recommended that much columns in a table.) In SQLite docs,

> Maximum Number Of Columns
>
> The maximum number of columns is 32767 in a table. The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000.

I rebuilded sqlite3.dll with custom parameters, so made SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN constant greater than my need. [I used this part on the documentation for building custom dll.](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html#building_a_windows_dll)

But when I tried to use this dll for managing SQLite db file, I coudn't find where it's located.

C# app I'm developing is using *System.Data.SQLite.Core* package and it calls SQLite.Interop.dll.

How to make my C# (.net Framework) app to use my custom built sqlite3.dll

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same problem yesterday. The thing is, when you have a look at System.Data.Sqlite.Core in Visual Studio, you will notice that its compile time assembly is System.Data.Sqlite.dll and as you wrote, it calls Sqlite.Interop.dll.

So you need to customize Sqlite.Interop.dll instead of sqlite3.dll.
In our case we replaced Sqlite.Interop.dll that was under this (relative) path, yours may differ based on your runtime, package version etc.:

.nuget\packages\stub.system.data.sqlite.core.netstandard\1.0.113.2\runtimes\win-x64\native

Comment: This question is too old for me to remember details, but I'm guessing there is sqlite,interop source code too. If it's, I'm marking this as solved.